# number with subscript in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I would like to use `output-decimal-marker = {--}` in siunitx to align a column with molecular transitions where the states are separated by --. However I get a Missing $ inserted error when the state includes a subscript.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{ S[output-decimal-marker = {--}] }
    3_1.2_1
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

How could this work for numbers with subscripts?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You haven't specified the _input_ decimal marker to be `--` (I'm not sure it's even possible) and so `siunitx` chokes on the first `-` as a misplaced minus sign. Use `3.2` as input instead.

Comment: Or use the option `input-decimal-markers`

Comment: Thanks, using 3.2 as input worked. I could not define the input marker as -- because it looks that only single characters are accepted.

Comment: @MigueldeVal-Borro `3\textsubscript{1}` is not a number, so `siunitx` can't do its job.

Comment: By the way, using `output-decimal-marker = {\textendash}` works for the non-math content. On that note, `$3_1$` isn't a number also. Depending on your case (can you show more examples of numbers/subscripts) a manual approach may be doable.

Comment: Do you want the -- to be an endash or two minusses?

Comment: I wanted to have an en-dash as decimal marker. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want something like that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{ S[output-decimal-marker={\text{--}},parse-numbers=false] }
    3_1.2_1
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably with `output-decimal-marker = {\text{--}}` to get an en-dash rather than two minus signs.